# Storing Columns names and their values in java from SQLITE

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to save the columns names and their values in an array list of strings, but I have not succeeded yet. 
Here is the Select function I'm trying to create.

```
public ArrayList<String[]> sqliteSelect(String sql)
{
    Statement stmt = null;
    ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    try {
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        int colCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String[] row = new String[colCount];
            for(int i=0; i<colCount;i++)
            {
                row[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
            }
            result.add(row);
        }
        stmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Everything looks fine but when I reach the point to add the results I have into the array list, it doesn't push the correct values. 
How can I optimize this so I can get the columns names with their respected values:
e.g of the desired list: `{<userid,01>,<value,20>}`

Comment: Create some kind of pojo representing the column values for row, use this in your List. You could use a HashMap for EACH column, but that seems excessive

Comment: If you want to retrieve the column name then you should create a persistent `ResultSetMetaData` object (instead of using an ephemeral one just to `.getColumnCount()`) and then use `.getColumnName()` on that object. Right now all you are saving is the [String representation of the] *value* for each column from the `ResultSet` object.

Comment: I want to get both them. Also, the current method I have is not working as it should be (it is not storing the values in the array list)

Comment: So what *is* in the `result` ArrayList  when your method returns it?